# How to do select query between dates of two datetime picker?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datetimepicker

I have to datetimepickers FromDate and ToDate, and want to do select data between to dates, 
I have written the query

```
select  * from tbl where pDate>='" + dtpFrom.value + "'and pDate<='" + dtpTo.value + "'");
```

This query giving error

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

But datatype is Date/Time in ms access table.

Comment: Heard of sql injection? Try using the string representation of the date object

Comment: I am using ms access database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you try to put single quotes for your `DateTime` values. `#` for dates and `'` for strings **but** they required for *literal* SQL queries.

If you use parameterize queries, you will not need them.

```
using(var con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "select * from tbl where pDate >= ? and pDate <= ?"
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtpFrom.Value);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", dtpTo.Value);
   ...
   ...
}
```